# Could java regex match a string which exists or not?

Tags: java, regex

I want to match the following strings:

```
<a href="http://xyz">xyz</a>
<a href="https://xyz">xyz</a>
<a href="xyz">xyz</a>
```

and I tried to use the regex but failed:

```
<a href="((http://|https://|).+)">\1</a>
```

What is the correct solution to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following regex does that:

```
<a\s+href="(?:https?://)?([^"]+)">\1</a>
```

An explanation:

```
<a\s+href="       # match `<a href="`
(?:https?://)?    # optionally match `http://` or `https://`
([^"]+)           # match one or more chars other than `"`, and store it in group 1
">                # match `">`
\1                # match the same as group 1
</a>              # match `</a>`
```

A Java demo:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tests = {
                "<a href=\"http://xyz\">xyz</a>",
                "<a href=\"https://xyz\">xyz</a>",
                "<a href=\"xyz\">xyz</a>",
                "<a href=\"xyz\">xyzzz</a>"
        };
        String regex = "<a\\s+href=\"(?:https?://)?([^\"]+)\">\\1</a>";
        for(String test : tests) {
            System.out.println(test.matches(regex));
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
true
true
true
false
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the great explanation!

Comment: I'd like to give a +2 here for the great explanation of the regex

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you need:

```
<a href="(https?://)?(.+)">\2</a>
```